# How can I contact the author to tell about an extension I made for his program?

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub. In fact, I have just made an account only to send the author of [this program](https://github.com/nu774/sudo-for-cygwin) a message informing about an [small extension](https://superuser.com/questions/741345/practical-closest-to-the-classical-linux-one-way-to-use-automate-sudo-for-cy) I have developed for his program.

But I can not find a way to contact the author, nor report it in the programming branch.

Could someone please explain the method?

Comment: There isn't a way.  If the author has not supplied the information to contact him you cannot contact him.

Comment: @slhck, if this question is off-topic, maybe it should be posted at StackOverFlow? It didn't seem to me as a programming question, so I asked it at SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

First to answer your question: his user profile refers to a website which has his email address at the bottom.

Normally on Github to push additions/fixes to upstream:

- Fork the repository
- Commit the change in your version of the repository
- Create a pull request back to the original repository (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request)

Comment: Cool, @mtak. But my script is not a change in the original repository, but rather a program that executes its program and closes it automatically after a given time. So I think I will contact him via eMail, as long as we have finally found it. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [opening an issue](https://github.com/nu774/sudo-for-cygwin/issues)?

Despite the name, [GitHub issues](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/) are used for more than just bug tracking. They're also a great way to reach out to the maintainer with questions or comments about their projects, or even to just [say thanks](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16731).